# how to hide the validation message in kendoUI

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI framework.
I am trying to implement validation for my `widgets(textbox,dropdown)`.
I don't want to display validation message while validating a widget,
for this I have implemented like,
I put

```
  required="required" validationMessage=""
```

also

```
$("#<validationElement> span.k-tooltip-validation").hide();
```

but still I am getting the message.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the validation message relating to the field(s) in question:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TheAttribute)
```